# My tapping won't register in unity (android app)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make an game for play store that I have already made for app store.
When I tap on the screen he jumps everytime i tap in iOS. But in android it seems harder to jump and sometimes he doesn't jump when I tap.

Here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FlyControll : MonoBehaviour {
    public float jumpBaseVelocity = 1.5f;
    public float jumpForce = 140f;
    public float headUpAngle = 25f;
    public float headDownAngle = -90f;
    public float headUpSpeed = 100f;
    public float headDownSpeed = 3f;
    public AudioSource[] audios;
    public float floatDistance = 0.05f;
    public float floatSpeed = 2f;
    public GameObject readyInfo;
    public bool canPlay = true;

    [HideInInspector]
    public bool isPlaying;
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool isDied;

    private Animator animator;
    private bool jump;
    private bool isFlyingUp;
    private bool isFallingDown;
    private double maxMagnitude;
    private double minMagnitude;
    private double minMagnitudeAtStart;
    private float floatStartPos;
    private int floatDirection = 1;
    private float topBorder;

    void Awake () {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator> ();
        int armorType = Random.Range(0, 3);
        animator.SetInteger("armorType", armorType);
        floatStartPos = transform.position.y;
        minMagnitudeAtStart = 9.8 * rigidbody2D.gravityScale;
        float dist = (transform.position - Camera.main.transform.position).z;
        topBorder = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0,1,dist)).y;
    }

    void Update() {
        if (canPlay) {
            if (!isDied) {
                if (isPlaying) {
                    if (isFlyingUp) {
                        rotateUp ();
                    } else if (isFallingDown) {
                        rotateDown ();
                    }
                } else {
                    floatUpAndDown();
                }
            } else {
                rotateDown();           
            }   
        } else {
            floatUpAndDown();
        }

    }

    private void floatUpAndDown() {
        if (floatDirection == 1) {
            if (transform.position.y < floatStartPos + floatDistance) {
                transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, new Vector3 (transform.position.x, floatStartPos + floatDistance + 3, 0), floatSpeed / 1000);
            } else {
                floatDirection = -1;
            }
        } else {
            if (transform.position.y > floatStartPos - floatDistance) {
                transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, new Vector3 (transform.position.x, floatStartPos - floatDistance - 3, 0), floatSpeed / 1000);
            } else {
                floatDirection = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate () {
        if (canPlay && !isDied) {
            checkJump();

            if (!isPlaying && jump) {
                isPlaying = true;
                readyInfo.GetComponent<ReadyControll>().hide();
                animator.SetTrigger ("jump");
                // make the bird could fall down
                animator.applyRootMotion = false;
            }

            if (isPlaying) {
                if(jump) {      
                    isFlyingUp = true;
                    isFallingDown = false;          
                    minMagnitude = minMagnitudeAtStart;
                    maxMagnitude = 0f;              
                    rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(0f, jumpBaseVelocity);               

                    // Add a vertical force to the player.          
                    rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpForce));   

                    audios[0].Play();

                    // Make sure the player can't jump again until the jump conditions are satisfied.
                    jump = false;
                }

                double currentMagnitude = rigidbody2D.velocity.magnitude;

                if (isFlyingUp) {                               
                    if (maxMagnitude <= currentMagnitude) {
                        maxMagnitude = currentMagnitude;
                    } else {                    
                        if (minMagnitude >= currentMagnitude) {
                            minMagnitude = currentMagnitude;
                        } else {
                            isFlyingUp = false;
                            isFallingDown = true;
                            maxMagnitude = 0;
                            minMagnitude = minMagnitudeAtStart;
                        }                                   
                    }                       
                } 

                if (isFallingDown) {        
                    if (maxMagnitude <= currentMagnitude) {
                        maxMagnitude = currentMagnitude;
                    } else {
                        if (minMagnitude >= currentMagnitude) {
                            minMagnitude = currentMagnitude;
                        } else {
                            isFallingDown = false;
                            maxMagnitude = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }   

                if(transform.position.y > topBorder) {
                    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, topBorder, transform.position.z);
                }
            } 
        } 
    }

    private void checkJump() {
        jump = Input.anyKeyDown;
    }

    private void rotateUp() {
//      transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, headUpAngle), Time.deltaTime * headUpSpeed);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, headUpAngle); 
    }

    private void rotateDown() {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, headDownAngle), Time.deltaTime * headDownSpeed);
    }

       void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) {
        rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, headDownAngle);
        if(!isDied) {
            audios[1].Play();
            animator.SetTrigger("dead");
            iTween.ShakePosition(Camera.main.gameObject, new Vector3(0.3f, 0.3f, 0), 0.5f);
        }       
        isDied = true;
        isPlaying = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's always good practice not to use input things in FixedUpdate () as it is intended for physics. Use input checking in Update().